# Cleveref messes up theoremstyles

Tags: theorems, cleveref

I use different `theorem` enviroments that should in theory all have the same style due to my code. They do as long as I don't load the `cleveref` package. If I load it, only corollary stays the same. How can I make `cleveref` to behave ( = to not disturb the styles) ?!

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}\numberwithin{corollary}{chapter}
\newtheorem{example}[corollary]{Example}
\newtheorem{lemma}[corollary]{Lemma}
\begin{document}

\begin{corollary}
A corollary.
\end{corollary}

\begin{example}
An example.
\end{example}

\begin{lemma}
A lemma.
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

The messed up version looks like this:

[image]

And what I want is that all theorem environments look like the corollary. As I said, they do if I don't load cleveref.

Comment: Load `cleveref` after the styles!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my opinion the `amsbook` class takes the wrong approach about theorems: it defines a slightly different structure from `amsthm` and fakes this package being loaded, so putting `cleveref` at stake, because this package does as if `amsthm` were actually loaded.

My solution is to forget about the setup made by the class and returning to `amsthm`, defining a new theorem style that emulates what `amsbook` does to begin with. A bit complicated, but it ensures cooperation with `cleveref`.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\usepackage{amsmath}

% nullify amsbook setup about theorems
\expandafter\let\csname ver@amsthm.sty\endcsname\relax
\let\theoremstyle\relax
\let\newtheoremstyle\relax
\let\pushQED\relax
\let\popQED\relax
\let\qedhere\relax
\let\mathqed\relax
\let\openbox\relax
\let\proof\relax\let\endproof\relax
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}

% make a new setup that emulates `amsbook`
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thm@space@setup}{% like amsbook does
  \thm@preskip=.5\baselineskip\@plus.2\baselineskip \@minus.2\baselineskip
  \thm@postskip=\thm@preskip
}
\newtheoremstyle{amsplain}
{\thm@preskip}
{\thm@postskip}
{\itshape}
{\parindent}
{\scshape}
{.}
{ }
{}
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{amsplain}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[chapter]
\newtheorem{example}[corollary]{Example}
\newtheorem{lemma}[corollary]{Lemma}

\begin{document}

Some text before so that it shows indentation
and let's go on until the text breaks across lines
to show also the left margin.

\begin{corollary}
A corollary.
\end{corollary}

\begin{example}
An example.
\end{example}

\begin{lemma}
A lemma.
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works for me, but only if I load cleveref last. If I load it at the same spot where you do (in my actual document), I get a lot of ?? as references.

Comment: @Kjara  `cleveref` should always be the last package

Answer (score 6):

`cleveref` does a lot of sophisticated things with counters and references, using it before  `\newtheorem{example}` etc. will not inform `cleveref` that `example` should use the `corollary` counter etc. (the same for `lemma` too then)

**General rule: Load `cleveref` as the last package, even after `hyperref`!!!**

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}\numberwithin{corollary}{chapter}
\newtheorem{example}[corollary]{Example}
\newtheorem{lemma}[corollary]{Lemma}


\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{corollary}
A corollary.
\end{corollary}

\begin{example}
An example.
\end{example}

\begin{lemma}
A lemma.
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, does not work. Yes, it fixes the theorem styles, but the references (I mainly use \Cref) do not work anymore! I only get a lot of ?? for most (not all) references.

Comment: @Kjara: `\Cref` works! If this is not the case for your document, there is apparently something wrong with it, but I don't know what you did in it. It would have been nice to give me a chance to 'correct' something, but now another answer is accepted. :-(