# Defining a double star (**) for theorem environment

Tags: environments, amsthm, starred-version, newtheorem

This is a follow-up question of [QED symbol after statements without proof](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334082), and I am really not sure whether this is the right approach to solve the problem raised there. But it seems to solve all situations I encounter perfectly, so I will try...

The theorem environment has the usual version with numbering and a `*`'ed version without numbering. I would now like to have another `**`'ed (or something similar) version that puts something around the theorem environment.

Here is what I currently need to do:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}[\unskip\nopunct]
\begin{theorem}
    $e^{2\pi i} = 1$. \qedhere
\end{theorem}
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}[\unskip\nopunct]
\begin{corollary}[{myref}]
    The expression $e^{2\pi i} - 1$ equals $0$. Moreover, there is more text to actually add here. \qedhere
\end{corollary}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

and I want to avoid adding the `\begin{proof}[\unskip\nopunct]` and the `\end{proof}` myself, but get this automatically using a double star in both situations.

It might actually be better to *interchange the order of the proof and the theorem environment*, so a solution that provides that version would also be appreciated!

That is

```
\begin{myXYZ**}[...]
    ...
\end{myXYZ**}
```

(with `myXYZ` defined as a theorem environment in the header) should simply translate into

```
\begin{proof}[\unskip\nopunct]
\begin{myXYZ}[...]
    ...
\end{myXYZ}
\end{proof}
```

Is this (or the `**` replaced with something else, independent of using theorem or lemma or proposition) possible?

Comment: Have you tried `\newenvironment{theorem**}[1][]{\begin{proof}[\unskip\nopunct]\begin{theorem}[#1]}{\end{theorem}\end{proof}}`?

Comment: This does not seem to behave like the usual theorem environment with only having adding a proof environment around. More immportantly, I would actually also want this to be independent of ``theorem`` but it should work equally well with ``lemma`` and any other theorem-like environment in the very same way without having to define it for each of these independently.

Comment: How about providing the foundation to start from in the form of a minimal example that shows your setup, including the expected output (even if you have to hard-code it).

Comment: @Werner: I am not sure it is clearer now, but I tried to add a mwe.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're about. Doesn't the `\addqed` macro I proposed do the job without any additional `proof` environment around? One might add a further abstraction layer, but I don't think that `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}\addqed{theorem}` is so long to type. Besides it was your request *not* to define environments with an additional `*`.

Comment: Thanks for your solutions there and here, and sorry about not being exact enough in what I would like to have! Indeed, after playing with your old solution, I realized that I basically look like the theorem environment to behave like the ams proof environment, so that's the reason for this second question.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this solves your problem. I define a `\varnewtheorem` command with the same syntax as `\newtheorem`, but that creates four variants for each label we call. So with `\varnewtheorem{foo}{Foo}` we create the four environments

- `foo` (theorem, proof follows)
- `foo*` (unnumbered theorem, proof follows)
- `foo+` (theorem, no proof)
- `foo*+` (unnumbered theorem, no proof)

The syntax accepts the optional arguments as usual.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\varnewtheorem}{momo}
 {
  \IfValueTF{#4}
   {\newtheorem{#1}{#3}[#4]}
    {
     \IfValueTF{#2}
      {\newtheorem{#1}[#2]{#3}}
      {\newtheorem{#1}{#3}}
    }
  \newtheorem*{#1*}{#3}
  \newenvironment{#1+}
   {\pushQED{\qed}\begin{#1}}
   {\popQED\end{#1}}
  \newenvironment{#1*+}
   {\pushQED{\qed}\begin{#1*}}
   {\popQED\end{#1*}}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\varnewtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\varnewtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{proposition}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}

\begin{theorem}
A standard theorem statement
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem*}
A standard unnumbered theorem statement
\end{theorem*}

\begin{theorem+}
A theorem statement without proof
\end{theorem+}

\begin{theorem*+}
An unnumbered theorem statement without proof
\end{theorem*+}


\begin{proposition}
A standard theorem statement
\end{proposition}

\begin{proposition*}
A standard unnumbered theorem statement
\end{proposition*}

\begin{proposition+}
A theorem statement without proof
\end{proposition+}

\begin{proposition*+}
An unnumbered theorem statement without proof
\end{proposition*+}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, I really like this solution, I will use this and the one by @Werner to see which seems more natural to use.

Answer (score 2):

For each `\newtheorem{X}`, you can call the below function `\doublestarenv{X}` to create an `X**` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\newcommand{\doublestarenv}[1]{%
  \newenvironment{#1**}[1][]
    {\proof[\unskip\nopunct]
     \csname #1\endcsname[##1]}
    {\csname end#1\endcsname
     \endproof}%
}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}

\doublestarenv{theorem}
\doublestarenv{corollary}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}[\unskip\nopunct]
\begin{theorem}
    $e^{2\pi i} = 1$. \qedhere
\end{theorem}
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}[\unskip\nopunct]
\begin{corollary}[{myref}]
    The expression $e^{2\pi i} - 1$ equals $0$. Moreover, there is more text to actually add here. \qedhere
\end{corollary}
\end{proof}

\begin{theorem**}
    $e^{2\pi i} = 1$. \qedhere
\end{theorem**}

\begin{corollary**}[{myref}]
    The expression $e^{2\pi i} - 1$ equals $0$. Moreover, there is more text to actually add here. \qedhere
\end{corollary**}

\end{document}
```

---

You can automate this process by updating `\newtheorem` to automatically execute `\doublestarenv`:

```
\newcommand{\doublestarenv}[1]{%
  \newenvironment{#1**}[1][]
    {\proof[\unskip\nopunct]
     \csname #1\endcsname[##1]}
    {\csname end#1\endcsname
     \endproof}%
}

\usepackage{xparse}

\let\oldnewtheorem\newtheorem
\RenewDocumentCommand{\newtheorem}{ m o m o }{%
  \IfValueTF{#2}
    {\edef\x{\noexpand\oldnewtheorem{#1}[#2]{#3}}}
    {\IfValueTF{#4}
       {\edef\x{\noexpand\oldnewtheorem{#1}{#3}[#4]}}
       {\edef\x{\noexpand\oldnewtheorem{#1}{#3}}}%
    }%
  \x\doublestarenv{#1}%
}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
```

Comment: Many thanks, this solution is closer to the actual question, but the outcome seems to be basically the same as in @egreg's solution. I will play with both to see which seems more natural to use.

Answer (score 1):

Here is @egreg's `theorem+` approach done with the package `create-theorem`. Take the environment `theorem` as an example, it begins by creating `theorem` and its starred variant via the key `create starred version`, and then uses `copy existed` to copy their definitions respectively and `qed` to add the QED symbol.

You may of course name the `theorem+` as `theorem**` and `theorem*+` as `theorem***`, it's your call.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{create-theorem}
\CreateTheorem { theorem } { parent counter = chapter, create starred version }
\CreateTheorem { theorem+ } { copy existed = theorem, qed }
\CreateTheorem { theorem*+ } { copy existed = theorem*, qed }
\CreateTheorem { proposition } { shared counter = theorem, create starred version }
\CreateTheorem { proposition+ } { copy existed = proposition, qed }
\CreateTheorem { proposition*+ } { copy existed = proposition*, qed }

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}

\begin{theorem}
A standard theorem statement
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem*}
A standard unnumbered theorem statement
\end{theorem*}

\begin{theorem+}
A theorem statement without proof
\end{theorem+}

\begin{theorem*+}
An unnumbered theorem statement without proof
\end{theorem*+}


\begin{proposition}
A standard theorem statement
\end{proposition}

\begin{proposition*}
A standard unnumbered theorem statement
\end{proposition*}

\begin{proposition+}
A theorem statement without proof
\end{proposition+}

\begin{proposition*+}
An unnumbered theorem statement without proof
\end{proposition*+}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `create-theorem` does not work very well with `amsbook`, in that:

1. The `\qedsymbol` in `amsbook` somehow shows as `\Lambda`. This is not a big issue through, you can explicitly write the option as `qed = \square` (provided that `\square` is defined, for example via `amssymb`).
2. The big issue is that `create-theorem` loads `cleveref` internally, which is known to be incompatible with the class `amsbook`. A workaround can be seen in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/274871) -- however, the theorem styles would be broken.